# MSAccess - Query using a Table as Criteria

Tags: ms-access

I think a basic question, I know I have done similar in past.  Looking for a quick pointer to get me running:

I have a large listing of `[Contacts]` (220K records) in a single table containing a field called `[Contacts].[Title]`.  In a separate table called `[Include]` I have a collection of title substrings I'd like to act as a filtering criteria.  Example:  Title like `*manager*`, or like `*director*`, etc... from the `[Include].[String]` list.

Essentially (pseudo):
`Select * from [Contacts] where [Contacts].[Title] is like *[Include].[String]*;`

I am unclear how to JOIN these 2 tables or construct the SQL/Query.

Suggestions?

Follow-up, This produces the desired result

```
SELECT Contacts.Title
FROM Contacts 
INNER JOIN Include ON Contacts.Title like '*' & Include.String & '*';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access inner join with inexact matching (wildcard or similar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503168/ms-access-inner-join-with-inexact-matching-wildcard-or-similar)

Comment: Yeah, June is right, use `'*' & [Include].[String] & '*'`  and you should be giood to go.

Comment: You are now comparing to the STRING `"[Include].[String]"`, not to the field.

Comment: That's it!  Thanks for the guidance. - SQL Updated above.