# MSAccess - Exclusion Join w/Wildcard?

Tags: ms-access

I had good success ([MSAccess - Query using a Table as Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833046/msaccess-query-using-a-table-as-criteria)) joining a Contacts table when Title matches a substring contained in an Include table using:

```
SELECT Contacts.Title
FROM Contacts 
INNER JOIN Include ON Contacts.Title like '*' & Include.String & '*';
```

I think I now need to go further and Exclude some titles, using an Exclude table.  Examples: The above approach properly grabbed the "CEO", but also grabbed the "CEO Admin Assistant", which I do not want.

The following is returning all rows; guessing because its using an .AND. not an .OR. comparing the entries in my Exclude list.

```
SELECT Contacts.Title
FROM Contacts 
INNER JOIN Exclude ON Contacts.Title not like '*' & Exclude.String & '*';
```

Any suggestions how to accomplish the desired Exclusion using a table?

Comment: Maybe Regular Expressions could be useful https://www.regular-expressions.info/ and possibly with a `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field NOT IN (SELECT …)` nested query.

Comment: ...and Where not exists ( select * from exclude where contacts.title like '*' & exclude.string & '*' )

Comment: ...although exists is slow, if you're bothered about performance do a left outer join eg select contacts.title from contact left outer join exclude on ...  where exclude.string is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `inner join` with `not like` in the join criteria will yield a **one-to-many relationship**, since, for each row in Contacts, there are likely to be **many** records in Exclude which the Contacts record is ***not like*** and only **one** record that it ***is like***.

Instead, if you wanted to continue using the calculated join criteria (as opposed to using `not in` or `not exists` with a subquery), I would suggest using a `left join` on the Exclude table and an `is null` condition within the `where` clause to select only those records which don't have a matching record in Exclude, e.g.:

```sql
select contacts.title 
from contacts left join exclude on contacts.title like '*' & exclude.string & '*'
where exclude.string is null
```

Comment: Lee Mac, thanks for the suggestions.  This seems to do exactly what I need!