# MS Access: How to use value derived from subquery in LIKE condition with wildcards?

Tags: sql, ms-access

In MS Access I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Budget WHERE Budget.[EXPENSE_NAME] Like '*Temps/Seasonal Employees*'
```

This finds over 40 matches.

There is a category table with category display name `Temps/Seasonal Employees` which gets used to generate the longer `EXPENSE_NAME` of a Budget record.  To improve the query by avoiding wonky-looking, hardcoded changeable stings, I'd rather use a more consistent code name.  (The display name was actually changed recently, requiring several queries to be updated.)

The wonky-looking string `Temps/Seasonal Employees` can be acquired by looking up the code name via:

```
SELECT COST_DISPLAY FROM CostType WHERE CODE_NAME = 'TEMP_EMPLOYEE'
```

This finds exactly one match, with one column, thus one string, namely `Temps/Seasonal Employees`.

It seems logical that I could substitute the second query into the first one for `Temps/Seasonal Employees` via:

```
SELECT * FROM Budget WHERE Budget.[EXPENSE_NAME] Like 
'*' & (SELECT COST_DISPLAY FROM CostType WHERE CODE_NAME = 'TEMP_EMPLOYEE') & '*'
```

This finds zero matches.  Likewise if move the wildcards into the subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM Budget WHERE Budget.[EXPENSE_NAME] Like
(SELECT '*' & COST_DISPLAY & '*' FROM CostType WHERE CODE_NAME = 'TEMP_EMPLOYEE')
```

I realized that Access might be seeing the subquery results as a list of one item instead of a string, so I tried the last two queries with `TOP 1` in the subquery, but that made no difference.

Is there another way to do this, or is what I'm trying to accomplish not possible?

Comment: The first attempted revision you posted works for me.

Comment: Can do inexact JOIN. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503168/ms-access-inner-join-with-inexact-matching-wildcard-or-similar. Beware, do not view query in Design, only SQLView.

Answer (score 0):

This seems overly complex and I doubt if it would work.

In such case I would join the two tables (not validated in Access):

```
SELECT
    Budget.*
FROM
    Budget
    inner join CostType on CostType.COST_DISPLAY = Budget.[EXPENSE_NAME]
WHERE
    CostType.CODE_NAME = 'TEMP_EMPLOYEE'
```

**But** if `CostType.CODE_NAME` is the key in CostType table then it would be better to change data model by adding a column `Budget.CODE_NAME` in Budget with a 1:n relationship, and then remove `Budget.[EXPENSE_NAME]`.

Comment: This overlooks the need for the wildcards: `Budget.[EXPENSE_NAME]` _contains_ the value of `CostType.COST_DISPLAY` within a longer string, e.g. `Temps/Seasonal Employees-Training`, `Temps/Seasonal Employees-Uniforms`, etc.  Table `Budget` already has a foreign key to `CostType` which is of no use because sometimes it's something very different like `Manpower`.  (This is a horribly structured project.)

Answer (score 0):

It is should work, only one record must be returned, and I would expect the concatenating to go like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Budget 
WHERE Budget.[EXPENSE_NAME] Like
    (SELECT TOP 1 "'*" & COST_DISPLAY & "*'" FROM CostType 
    WHERE CODE_NAME = 'TEMP_EMPLOYEE')
```

Comment: OP said query returned only one record so TOP 1 shouldn't make any difference but does guarantee 1 record. I did a test with my data without TOP 1. Nested query works but wildcards are in outer query.

Comment: @June7: Yes, but that Access doesn't know. So, better to be explicit.